# C++ longest word occurrence, got error with the '\0'

Tags: c++

The problem is to find the longest word in an input string given by keyboard, the program runs well, it finds the longest word except for the fact that if the longest word in question is at the very end of the input (for example, Hello Classroom!) the program will return Hello and not Classroom! because of the '\0' i think.

here's the code:

```
    int main() {

    string s;
    string tmp_longest;
    string longest;

    getline(cin, s);

    int size = s.length();

    int full_counter = 0, no_space_counter = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        full_counter++;
        if (s.at(i) != ' ') {
            no_space_counter++;
            tmp_longest += s.at(i);
        }
        else if (s.at(i) == ' ' || s.at(i) == '\0') { // i think that's the problem but cant figure it out
            if (tmp_longest.length() > longest.length())
                longest = tmp_longest;

            tmp_longest = "";


        }
    }

    cout << "Longest word: " << longest << endl;
    cout << "Character of the word: " << longest.length() << endl;
    cout << "String length: " << full_counter << endl;
    cout << "String length (without spaces): " << no_space_counter << endl;;

}
```

i'm doing a check everytime the for encounter a space, so i can check the actual word memorized in longest with the last memorized in.

here some img that could explain the problem better.

[image: First image]

[image: Second image]

Comment: This is a good time to learn how to use your debugger.

Comment: yes, totally it is. do you have any good source or can i just view that on the vs documentation?

Comment: look for whitespace not for just space,  whitespace can be `'\t'` (tab) or `'\r'`. better way is to use `stringstream` to split a line to words.

Comment: @SHR thanks for the info, i'm going to see the stream family operation on the stroustrup's book.

Comment: [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
else if (s.at(i) == ' ' || s.at(i) == '\0')
```

is meaningless, because the last value of `i` is `s.length()-1`

After the end of the for loop, you need to repeat the lines

```
if (tmp_longest.length() > longest.length())
     longest = tmp_longest;
```

Comment: Obviously, because in the iteration the statement will be executed n-1 times, so dumb from me. So when is neither a word or a 'space' character it will exit from both the statement and do the comparison at the end of the for. So clear. Thank you for the precious help!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that `s.length()` returns the length of the string, *not* counting the   trailing `'\0'`. So your for loop doesn't ever get to the `'\0'` behind the last word.
To do this, you can simply change `for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)` to `for (int i = 0; i <= s.length(); i++)`. However you cannot access the `'\0'` via `s.at(i)`, because `s.at(i)` throws an exception if `i` is greater or equal to `s.length()`. But you can do this by indexing the underlying C string like this: `s.c_str()[i]`.

**Summary:**
Replace `for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)` with `for (int i = 0; i <= s.length(); i++)` and replace `s.at(i)` with `s.c_str()[i]`.

Comment: that's an amazing answer, thanks for the detailed and accurate explanation of the problem, it seems an interesting and elegant solution. I tried and understood the "why" behind your code, but unfortunately, still dont work.